# Is there a way to automate logging in to multiple user accounts?

Tags: icloud, login, automation, headless

I have a mac mini that I'm using as a home server.

I have two accounts on the computer which are both set to download full resolution photos and to download all iCloud (Desktop and Documents) contents.  i.e., Optimize Storage is turned off.

This same computer is backed up locally to a time machine volume, takes scheduled superduper! clones, and is uploaded to an offsite backup service.  Yes, I am paranoid about backups.

I keep both accounts logged in at all times so that both my and my wife's full photo libraries and Desktop and Documents folders will always be present to be backed up.

The problem I'm having is that if the computer restarts, both accounts are logged out and I have to manually log in to them.  This is a problem when I leave town for any length of time, because if the computer restarts for any reason (power outage, someone turns it off, etc) then the syncing that I want will no longer be happening.

Is there any way to do this?  I'd prefer it to be a local solution, because I don't want my local network accessible in any way.

I am happy to write a complicated script/program and/or spend money on this problem in service of an elegant solution.

Thanks!